# I have several sets of unidentified Lego bags with no part number. How can I figure out what to build?

Tags: set-identification

I have a photo but it is too large to post. These were donated to me.

In fact, I have a huge tub of random Legos that were donated to me and I have no idea how to organize the parts. Most were not in Lego bags. The bags say @The Lego Group 2007 and each one has a single digit on it ( 2,3, 6, 9). There are no directions.

Comment: Welcome segurry! Unfortunately, those bags are very common and don't help in determining which set(s) you have. You will need to try and post a picture - that way we can help you identify the set(s). Can you try to reduce the size of your picture and upload it again?

Answer (score 4):

You must classify parts first and find out which parts you have. You can always use [Rebrickable website](http://www.rebrickable.com) which is a great system that gives you the sets you can build with your parts. Most difficult part of the answer is of course classifying the parts and upload them to your Rebrickable account but once you done you can find out what you have and google the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to find some details via http://brickset.com/sets/year-2007, be warned you will get a long list. If you have a bag numbered 9, then it must have been a big box. So try to sort by number of pieces in descending order.